# how to get second least column in a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some 8 columns in a table.All the columns are of same type integer.

```
|id  | marks_1 | marks_2 | marks_3|....|marks_7|
|1001|0        |20       |15      |....|25     |
|1002|20       |0        |11      |....|0      |
.
.
.
.
|1010|40       |0        |0       |....|25     |
```

I want to get the output as

```
|id  |marks   |
|1001|15      |
|1002|11      |
```

I tried getting the least of these columns using the LEAST() function of MySql.

```
SELECT id, LEAST(marks_1,marks_2,marks_3,marks_4,marks_5,marks_6,marks_7) AS marks from tbl_name
```

and it is working.

It fetches me

```
|id  |marks   |
|1001|0       |
|1002|0       |
```

but I need the second least. i.e non-zero record from the row.

Comment: There isn't actually an easy way to do this, primarily because you should not be storing the data in separate columns.  They should be in separate rows.

Comment: Take the example as each columns are marks. I can't make marks as rows and student id as columns. it doesn't make sense

Comment: No, your table design does not make sense. You could add more realistic example data and we might be able to help you fix your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you what you want is the minimum number that is greater than `0`, then you can *unpivot* your table and apply grouping to it:

```
SELECT id, MIN(c)
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          CASE t2.n
             WHEN 1 THEN col_1
             WHEN 2 THEN col_2
             WHEN 3 THEN col_3
             WHEN 4 THEN col_4
             WHEN 5 THEN col_5
             WHEN 6 THEN col_6
             WHEN 7 THEN col_7
          END AS c
   FROM mytable AS t1
   CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL
     SELECT 7) AS t2) AS x
WHERE x.c > 0   
GROUP BY id
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QKUL5700)

Comment: quote from the topic starter "but I need the second least. i.e non-zero record from the row." so your query cant be correct with MIN(c) function..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think the OP's statement is self contradictory, since, for example, the second highest number of the row with `id=1002` is still `0`. So, he possibly wants the smaller number that is greater than zero.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos exactly.. thats what I want.. and your query works like a charm :)

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos guess your right the topic starter didnt explain it correctly then..

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 SELECT t1.id, IFNULL(LEAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0)),
         COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.col_7, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_1, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_2, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_3, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_4, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_5, 0),NULLIF(t1.col_6, 0))),0) AS marks
       from tbl_name t1
```

Comment: your code does work.. but one small issue. if my entire row is zero it returns null. but @giorgosBetsos' answer solves even that by excluding that row.

Comment: I assumed that there was at least one value more than 0, but this can be easily solved, edit my answer, I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by normalizing the data and using variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from ((select id, col_1 as col, 'col_1' as colname from t) union all
            (select id, col_2 as col, 'col_2' as colname from t) union all
            . . .
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @id := -1) params
      order by id, col asc
     ) t
where rn = 2;
```

Note:  This version also gives the column name.  You need to fill in the `. . .` with all the other columns.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . LOL.  Yes, that would be the correct term.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is not nice, but also works:

```
SELECT
    id 
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col1 ORDER BY col1), ',', -3),',',1)
FROM (
    SELECT id, col1 FROM test_table
    UNION SELECT id, col2 FROM test_table
    UNION SELECT id, col3 FROM test_table
    UNION SELECT id, col4 FROM test_table
    UNION SELECT id, col5 FROM test_table
) AS t
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.col1
;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     id
    ->     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col1 ORDER BY col1), ',', -3),',',1)
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT id, col1 FROM test_table
    ->     UNION SELECT id, col2 FROM test_table
    ->     UNION SELECT id, col3 FROM test_table
    ->     UNION SELECT id, col4 FROM test_table
    ->     UNION SELECT id, col5 FROM test_table
    -> ) AS t
    -> GROUP BY t.id
    -> ORDER BY t.col1
    -> ;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col1 ORDER BY col1), ',', -3),',',1) |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 3                                                                                 |
|  2 | 6                                                                                 |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table;
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    3 |    2 |    5 |    4 |
|  2 |    7 |    8 |    6 |    3 |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```